# Raspberry Pi LXDE restore?

Tags: raspbian, lxde

I recently got a pi with an SD card from element14, preloaded with Raspian. I somehow damaged the filesystem and had to recopy the OS to the SD card. I used the 2012-12-16-wheezy-raspbian image from the official raspberry pi download page, but now when I run LXDE with 'startx' it tells me there is a problem with an xml file not having a starting '<', and I checked the file and saw that it was blank. There is no longer the raspberry pi logo on the desktop and the status bar is missing. How can I get it back to way it was 'out of the box'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically the easiest solution is to download the image again from the Raspberry Pi website and copy the image to the SD card again. Most likely some files made it across and some did not.